# updating on the basis of row num

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

hi i want to chunk the data on the basis of row num but im failing when im trying to update

```
 declare 
temp varchar2(50);
low varchar2(50);
upp varchar2(50);
begin
low :=0;

for i in ( SELECT 
TO_CHAR(FLOOR(rownum/10) * 10) as low, TO_CHAR(FLOOR(rownum/10) * 10 + 10 -1 ) AS upp
FROM emp
GROUP BY FLOOR(rownum/10)
ORDER BY FLOOR(rownum/10))
loop


  update emp set thd=2     where rownum>i.low and rownum<i.upp;
  commit;
 low:=low+1;
  dbms_output.put_line(i.low|| i.upp);


end loop;
end;
```

the code is updating the first 10 rec correctly but not updating the next cycles 20-30 30-40

any guess why

Comment: Is `rownum` a column within your table `emp`?

Comment: @FDavidov no its a psedo column

Comment: I know that in PL/SQL you can **get** the row number in a select, which means the _row number of the result_. I'm not sure what the meaning would be to use this number for an update (guessing, I would say **none**).

Comment: @FDavidov im trying to chunk the data into groups 
for that im trying to set the thd column e.g  for first ten rows in want t set thd coumn with 1 and for 20- 30 thd=2 and son on

Comment: Well, your `ORDER BY FLOOR(rownum/10)` is meaningless since `rownum` is assigned a value during the construction of the select. Imagine that you order by other field and also select rownum. You will still get 1,2,3,4,... even though the order of the records is completely different. You need to order by a different (physical) column (or set of columns that would yield a single record for each possible combination).

Comment: Another alternative is to retrieve your table into a cursor, loop through the cursor, and update the column of the record based on the other fields of the handled record (in each loop).

Comment: @FDavidov it will be huge overhead to iterate throgh cursor as im dealing with mre than 6 million records and it will compromise performance

Comment: Well, you are UPDATING 6 million records. This is going to take most of the time. Getting the records into the cursor is much the same as what you are doing, and looping though the cursor may add some time, but definitely much less that that used by the update. Before disqualifying a suggestion, it may be worth trying it, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: This is getting a bit out of topic. Question was where condition based on `rownum` is not working. If you need some advice about how to do update of 6 milions rows please redefine question. If we look on logic the query is going to update all rows with same value so whole discussion is pure theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle pseudocolumn `rownum` returns a number indicating the order in which Oracle selects the row from a table. You can use where `rownum < n`. But `rownum > n` will always return empty result set. Because first returned row is always `rownum = 1` and you expect it to be `> n`. That's why you get no rows update. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

If you have some id in table you can do that:

```
merge into emp e
using (select * from (select e2.*, row_number() over (order by id) r from emp e2) where r > 10 and r < 21) d
on (e.id = d.id)
when matched then update set thd = 2;
```

If you don't have an id you can use `cursor for update`.

Comment: He is not getting an error - he just gets no more rows updated, since there are no rows "where rownum > 9". This explains why there is only one round of updates - "where rownum > 0 and rownum < 10" (or whatever his computations) is fine, but the other times through the loop will update no rows.

Comment: @mathguy Yes you're right. I was thinking about error in sense of logic. I'll amend my answer

Comment: @mathguy there are 20 rows in my table so as per my understanding there are rows greater with rownum 9

Comment: We are in agreement. An "error" usually means code that leads to an error message - either a syntax error (like a missing parenthesis) which is caught at compile time, or a "runtime error" (like a string supposed to be a date, but where the month number is 14). A logic error in the sense you used it is usually called a "bug" - the code runs perfectly fine, but it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @fawad - you need to understand how ROWNUM is assigned. The first row is read from the stored table; it is assigned ROWNUM = 1, then the WHERE clause ROWNUM>9 rejects the row. The next row is brought in from the base table and ROWNUM = 1 is **reused** - it is given now to the second row, and it fails the WHERE condition too. You keep going and no row is ever "accepted", they are ALL rejected by the WHERE clause. Think about this for a minute to make sure you understand it, otherwise you may fall in this trap many times again in the future.

Comment: @fawad - Run SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ROWNUM > 1 and see what happens. (What do you EXPECT will happen?)

Comment: @mathguy i will got the no result set but is this mean we cant chunk the data on the basis of rownum ranges ??

Comment: @fawad just simply using `where rownum > n` will always result in empty set. So you can't chunk data that way. What you can do is `select * from (select t.*, rownum r from t) where r between n1 and n2;` In such query `rownum` will be assigned in inner query and the you can use it in outer by alias.